# Web API CORS Delete

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am using Angular JS + CORS + Web API. I am able to make an HTTP request for GET, POST and PUT. However i am getting an error while making a request for "DELETE".

"The requested resource does not support http method 'DELETE'."
my web api code is:

```
public void Delete(int id)
        {
            //code to remove data from DB.
        }
```

and my WebApiConfig class has the following settings

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }

public IEnumerable<Entity> Get()
    {
        return <List<Entity>>;
    }
```

my client code is :

```
   $http({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: 'http://example.com/api/<controller>/',
        data: {id :uId}
    }).success(function (data, status) {
        aleert('success');
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        alert('error');
    });

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://example.com/api/<controller>'
    }).success(function (data, status) {
        alert('success');
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        alert('error');
    });
```

What am i missing? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the web api code for GET, and the client code for a GET call?

Comment: Here is my GET Web API code:

public IEnumerable<Entity> Get()
        {
            return <List<Entity>>
        }
Here is the client call for GET:

$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'X-Domain-site here i.e. http://example.com/api/action'
        }).success(function (data, status) {
            // do your action here
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            alert('error');
        });

Please let me know if you are looking to fix a particular error, so that i can share my excerpts.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and put the code there

Comment: done. please let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

You must to put http verb to your Delete method:

```
[HttpDelete]
public void Delete(int id)
{
    //code to remove data from DB.
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this. and still i have the same error. I also have the below setting in my web.config without any help

<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>